# Removing OAuth 2.0 authentication from OpenAPI 3.0 definition in API Manager 4.0.1

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have a client application which will use the OpenAPI 3.0 definition generated from the API Manager in the Devportal.Our Client App support only two type of authentication mechanism (apikey and basic auth) so it don't accept the "OAuth2.0" type which exist in the swagger file by default .We tried to remove OAuth 2.0 from the publisher in the Application level security and set apikey and basic auth as an alternative .We thought that the swagger file will change OAuth2.0 to basic auth or apikey but it still the same .It was updated only in the API Defintion in the publisher Portal but not in the swagger file generated in the devPortal .

Is there any solution to remove this OAuth2.0 from the swagger file .

[image: Change Oauth2.0 by apikey]

Comment: At the moment it is not possible to remove the default security section in the Developer portal.

Comment: Why it is impossible to remove Oauth2.0 from OpenAPI 3.0 Defintion ?

Comment: You need to have the code changes for this. By design APIM adds this default security schema.

Comment: So can I override this default security schema by using API KEY ?